# woocommerce product custom field

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I have added custom field in woocommerce Products>General Tab. But I am not getting those custom fields value in response using following link:- http://yoursite.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/

My Code:-

```
//Display Fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );

//Save Fields
    add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );

    function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

        global $woocommerce, $post;

        echo '<div class="options_group">' ;
                 //Purchasing Cost
                woocommerce_wp_text_input(
                    array(
                        'id' => 'purchasing_cost',
                        'placeholder' => 'Purchasing Cost',
                        'label' => __('Purchasing Cost', 'woocommerce'),
                        'type' => 'text',                       
                        'show_in_rest' => true,         
                        'rest_base' => 'products',
                        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Products_Controller',
                    )
                );

                 //OverHead
                woocommerce_wp_text_input(
                    array(
                        'id' => 'overhead',
                        'placeholder' => 'Overhead',
                        'label' => __('Overhead', 'woocommerce'),
                        'type' => 'text',   
                        'show_in_rest' => true,
                        'rest_base' => 'products',
                        'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Products_Controller',
                    )
                );  
        echo '</div>';
    }

    //To Save data
    function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save($post_id) {
            //Purchasing Cost
             $woocommerce_purchasing_cost_field = $_POST['purchasing_cost'];
                if (!empty($woocommerce_purchasing_cost_field))
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'purchasing_cost', esc_attr($woocommerce_purchasing_cost_field));

            //OverHead
             $woocommerce_overhead_field = $_POST['overhead'];
                if (!empty($woocommerce_overhead_field))
                update_post_meta($post_id, 'overhead', esc_attr($woocommerce_overhead_field));
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should ad the custom field to product API response, try this
 (untested)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_product', 'custom_products_api_data', 90, 2 );
function custom_products_api_data( $response, $post ) {

// retrieve a custom field and add it to API response
$response->data['purchasing_cost'] = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'purchasing_cost', true );

return $response;
}
```

Comment: I tried but, It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to My Question

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'slug_register_purchasing' );

function slug_register_purchasing() {
        register_rest_field( 'product',
            'purchasing_cost',
            array(
                'get_callback'    => 'slug_get_purchasing_cost',
                'update_callback' => null,
                'schema'          => null,
            )
        );
    }

function slug_get_purchasing_cost( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_post_meta( $object[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'slug_register_overhead' );

function slug_register_overhead() {
    register_rest_field( 'product',
        'overhead',
        array(
            'get_callback'    => 'slug_get_overhead',
            'update_callback' => null,
            'schema'          => null,
        )
    );
}



function slug_get_overhead( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
    return get_post_meta( $object[ 'id' ], $field_name, true );
}
```

For Detailed Description 
http://v2.wp-api.org/extending/modifying/